how can I copy files from all subdirectory according to a specific file type
I have a Makefile that has a bash command that I need to convert to a Windows batch file.
The command is:
find "source" -type f -wholename '*/.bin/output/*.dll' -exec cp\{\} "./dest" \;

The idea of this command is to copy all DLL files in /.bin/output/ folders and copy them to the dest folder.
To my knowledge, there is no equivalent command for find.
Can someone help me with that?

check where command, it perform search for files

yes, there is a find command in Windows See find /? or the more advanced findstr /?. Although they don't have the ability to execute anything (Edit: same is true for where /?). You need a loop around it - see for /?. for /r "source" %f in (*.dll) do @echo %f | findstr /i "\\.bin\\output\\" && copy "%f" "dest", seems a good start point to me (which may require only minimal adaptions to your use-case)

I finally succeeded in solving this.
@echo off
 
set "sourceDir=%cd%"
set "destDir=%cd%\build"
set fileCount=0
 
if not exist "%destDir%" (
    mkdir "%destDir%"
)
 
for /r "%sourceDir%" %%d in (.bin) do (
    if exist "%%d\output" (
        for %%f in ("%%d\output\*.dll") do (
            copy "%%f" "%destDir%" >nul
            if not errorlevel 1 (
                set /a fileCount+=1
            )
        )
    )
)

This works as expected. Thanks to everyone who commented on this post.
